# List at start of a sentence

Tags: grammar, commas, lists

How would I correctly place a list at the start of a sentence? For example, how what is the correct way to write:

> Pens, markers, pencils I had it all.

If a comma doesn't work, could I use a hyphen like this:

> Pens, markers, pencils-I had it all.

Comment: I would personally use the fast-going-out-of-fashion semicolon, myself.

Comment: I'd probably use the dash.

Comment: I would use a comma. It may be a matter of taste. Don't use a hyphen though; hyphens have a different meaning. A dash is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An em dash (—), not a hyphen (and not a semicolon, space, or comma), is appropriate; see [this similar example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Inversion_of_the_function_of_a_colon).

Comment: Thanks. So in general, the dash phrase can come in the front(in addition to the middle or back)?

Comment: It certainly can.